# how to correctly find out the return type of a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

basically how to make following code compile?

I know it failed because compiler was trying to evaluate something like `([](int &i){})(0)` but how to solve the problem?

```
template <class TElement>
struct foo {
    TElement _e;
    foo(TElement e) : _e(e){}
    template <class Lambda>
    void bar(Lambda f) {
        using TResult = decltype(std::declval<Lambda>()(std::declval<TElement>()));
    }
};

int main() {

    foo<int>(0).bar([](int i){}); // compile
    foo<int>(0).bar([](int &&i){}); // compile
    foo<int>(0).bar([](int const &i){}); // compile
    foo<int>(0).bar([](int &i){}); // failed

}
```

Comment: You may use `foo<int&>(i).bar([](int &i){});`

Comment: @Jarod42 That'll make `_e` member have reference type, which might not be desired.

Comment: @jrok but `foo<int&>(0)` won't compile

Comment: Lambdas are not special. You can find out the return type of a lambda in the same way you can find the return type of another callable object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use following traits:

```
template <typename T>
struct return_type : return_type<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};
// For generic types, directly use the result of the signature of its 'operator()'

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct return_type<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = ReturnType;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Two ways.  First:

```
using TResult = decltype(f(_e));
```

or second:

```
using TResult = typename std::result_of<Lambda&(TElement&)>::type;
```

Your code implicity says that the TElement is a temprary/rvalue.  The `&` above makes them lvalues.

Comment: I don't see the need for `std::declval<Lambda>`. There's already `f` there.

Comment: And with first way, `foo<int>(0).bar([](int &&i){});` doesn't compile.

Comment: @jrok if the OP is goimg to pass `f` the member variable, it won't compile there either.  As they wanted the lambda takimg `int&` to work, I presume that was the case.  Which does suggest another improvement...

Answer (score 2):

You might resolve it with:

```
template <typename Lambda, typename T>
struct lambda_return_type {
    private:
    template<typename U>
    static constexpr auto check(U*) -> decltype(std::declval<Lambda>()(std::declval<U>()));

    template<typename U>
    static constexpr auto check(...) -> decltype(std::declval<Lambda>()(std::declval<U&>()));

    public:
    typedef decltype(check<T>(nullptr)) type;
};
```

and

```
void bar(Lambda f) {
    typedef typename lambda_return_type<Lambda, TElement>::type TResult;
}
```

Comment: Why `*(U*)nullptr` and not `std::declval<U&>()`?

Comment: @Yakk Thanks - it's a declval, now