# Get the type of the return value in C++

Tags: c++, types, c++14, decltype

Suppose we have a function `f` which returns a value of some unknown type (let's call it `T`) and takes a value of the type `T` as an argument (and possibly has some other arguments). How do I get the return type of `f` in C++14?

There is a way to do it if we know the know the argument types (via `std::result_of`). Is it possible if we know all the argument types except `T`?

Example:

```
template <class F> // F is functor with   T operator()(T a, T b)
class A {
    // Here I want to do
    // T some_function(T some_arg) { ... }
}
```

Comment: do you have a code sample of what you mean?

Comment: @MarcoA. yes, but it's sort of specific

Comment: `decltype(f(...))`, where `...` is filled with arguments of type that the function can take. So for instance, if f was `f(int, float)`, you would do `decltype(f(0, 0.f))`

Comment: @TheOne but I don't know all the argument types! I know all except the one I want to find

Comment: @MarcoA. added to the post

Comment: @wrwt: is `some_function` a template with one type parameter `T` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. No, T is the return type of functor F

Comment: @PiotrS. T is precisely the type I'm asking how to get

Comment: you can force the class F to have some typedef, like allocators must have ::pointer and stuff

Comment: What if `F` defines both `int operator()(int)` and `double operator()(double)`? What type would you return?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863090/how-to-correctly-find-out-the-return-type-of-a-lambda

Answer (score 16):

```
template <typename T>
struct return_type;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) &> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) &&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename T>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<T>::type;
```

*Test:*

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Functor
{
    int operator()(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
};

template <class F>
struct A
{
    using T = return_type_t<decltype(&F::operator())>;

    T some_function(T some_arg) { return some_arg; }
};

int main()
{
    A<Functor> a;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.some_function(1)), int>::value, "!");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d387dbf979fbbeb8)

Comment: can you add empty line between each template class? It is pretty hard to read it atm

Comment: Doesn't work for arbitrary functors, of course. And you should also have a partial specialization for a normal function type.

Comment: @T.C.: is `struct return_type<R(*)(Args...)>` what you call a specialization for *standard function type*? because it is already there

Comment: I was talking about `return_type<R (Args...)>`.

Comment: @T.C.: thanks, I didn't realize `decltype(func)` and `decltype(&func)` differ in type

Comment: This won’t work with a member function such as `int foo(int i, ...) const volatile&&;`!

Comment: @LucDanton: what does `...` stand for in your code?

Comment: It stands [for an ellipsis](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/154e6b00671b2741).

Comment: @LucDanton: so if you meant ellipsis, then I can't imagine someone declaring a member function with variadic args expressed with ellipsis, but I believe it can be extended to support it as well

Comment: @Piotr S. Can you please tell me why doesn't this work in C++11? Can it be done?

Comment: @LogicStuff what do you mean by "doesn't work in C++11" ?

Comment: @Piotr S. I'm using VS 2013, and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4d8tqpl4h30h7dr/AAAaRN0A6QH44AnqiK9zygN8a?dl=0) is the source and the output (if you don't defy opening unknown links). I haven't even instantiate any template. The source compiled fine on VS 2015.

Comment: @LogicStuff VS2013 doesn't fully support C++11

Comment: @Piotr S. Well, there's that :D Still, I wonder what's special about that use of variadic templates which seem to be causing the errors. I've already worked with them in VS 2013.

Comment: @Piot S. OK, now I see that it was caused by the overloads for ref-qualifiers, which don't yet exist in VS 2013.

Answer (score 5):

Building on @Piotr S.'s excellent answer, for arbitrary functor types, if you know that there's exactly one `operator()` overload with the right "pattern", so to speak, then you can do something like this:

```
// leave undefined
template<class C, class T>
T return_type_helper(T (C::*)(T));

template<class C, class T>
T return_type_helper(T (C::*)(T) const);

// 10 additional combinations of ref- and cv- qualifiers omitted, because I'm lazy

template<typename T>
using functor_return_type = decltype(return_type_helper(&T::operator()));
```

This activates overload resolution and template argument deduction to determine the right `operator()`.

And then you can combine those two:

```
template <typename... T>
struct voider { using type = void; };

template <typename... T>
using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct combined_return_type;

template<typename T>
struct combined_return_type<T, void_t<typename return_type<T>::type>> { 
    using type = typename return_type<T>::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct combined_return_type<T, void_t<functor_return_type<T>>> { 
    using type = functor_return_type<T>; 
};

template <typename T>
using return_type_t = typename combined_return_type<T>::type;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e512a6171889b12).