# Instantiate nested class template with a parameter of templated using declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

After reading the answers on [how to get a parameter types of a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/how-do-i-get-the-argument-types-of-a-function-pointer-in-a-variadic-template-cla) and [how to get the a return value of a function pointer (with cv-qualifier overloads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201835/get-the-type-of-the-return-value-in-c/26201959?noredirect=1#comment50488458_26201959), I decided to merge them into one `function_traits` class template:

```
#include <tuple>

using uint = unsigned int;

template <typename T>
struct function_traits;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct function_traits<R(Args...)>
{
    using return_t = R;
    static const uint args_count = sizeof...(Args);

    template <uint i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct function_traits<R(*)(Args...)>
{
    using return_t = R;
    static const uint args_count = sizeof...(Args);

    template <uint i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ... Args>
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(Args...)>
{
    using return_t = R;
    using class_t = C;
    static const uint args_count = sizeof...(Args);

    template <uint i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

// cv-qualifier overloads ...
```

The code above works fine, but I also wanted to provide a few `typedef`s to spare me the typing. However, the compiler gives me error on the `arg_t` when I try to instantiate the nested class template `arg` with template parameter `i`. I'm not that skilled with templates so it's possibly a basic thing I'm missing here. What is it?

```
template <typename T>
using return_t = typename function_traits<T>::return_t;

template <typename T>
using class_t = typename function_traits<T>::class_t;

template <typename T, uint i>
using arg_t = typename function_traits<T>::arg<i>::type;
//                                            ^
//                                    ';' expected here
```

Here's the output from [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9646e810cc48d0b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `arg<i>` is a member of a template, you need to specify in the code that it is a template.  You need to specify this because `arg` could be a template or not be a template depending on specializations of `function_traits`.  Members of templates need to be specified if they are types or templates.  You as the programmer need to tell the compiler that `arg<i>` is a template.  You can do that by doing this:

```
template <typename T, uint i>
using arg_t = typename function_traits<T>::template arg<i>::type;
```

It looks weird, but that's the way C++ is.

Comment: Thanks! Works on VS 2013.

Comment: Awesome! I'll note that in my answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with two-phase lookup. The issue is that `arg` is a dependent name.

Comment: @Barry I couldn't remember which it was when I answered.  I'll change the wording in my answer.