# replacement for std::binary_function

Tags: c++, c++11, deprecated

[`std::binary_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function) is deprecated now and is going to be deleted in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). I searched on different publications, but I couldn't find a exact way to replace it. I'd like to know how should I write the following code in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) style.

```cpp
template <class T>
inline T absolute(const T &x) {
    return (x >= 0) ? x : -x;
}

template <class T>
struct absoluteLess : public std::binary_function<T, T, bool> {
    bool operator()(const T &x, const T &y) const {
        return absolute(x) < absolute(y);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct absoluteGreater : public std::binary_function<T, T, bool> {
    bool operator()(T &x, T &y) const {
        return absolute(x) > absolute(y);
    }
};
```

#### EDIT

I'm using the functions in the following way:

```cpp
output[j] = *std::max_element(input.begin() + prev,
                              input.begin() + pos,
                              absoluteLess<float>());
```

`input` and `output` are `std::vector`s, inside a for-loop.

Comment: why you need it? type traits and decltype can figure out the type of `operator()`  without the needs of `binary_function`

Comment: How do you use these template functions? The answer depends on the usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22863957/642626 thats how you find out the arguments and return type of any callable object.

Comment: LLVM C++ standard library still using `binary_function` at the end of 2020 https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/functional  What is more `clang++ --std=c++17` still can compile code which uses  `binary_function`  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__functional_base

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, my advice is to watch [CppCon 2015: Stephan T. Lavavej "functional: What's New, And Proper Usage"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0). `std::binary_function` is mentioned on slide 36, at around 36 mins in the video. You can find the slides at github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015). It doesn't go into detail why you shouldn't use `std::binary_function`, but if you're using something that's been deprecated since C++11, then you would probably benefit from watching it.

If you want the actual rationale for not using it, try n4190:

> unary_function/binary_function were useful helpers when C++98-era
>   adaptors needed argument_type/etc. typedefs.  Such typedefs are
>   unnecessary given C++11's perfect forwarding, decltype, and so forth. 
>   (And they're inapplicable to overloaded/templated function call
>   operators.)  Even if a class wants to provide these typedefs for
>   backwards compatibility, it can do so directly (at a minor cost in
>   verbosity) instead of inheriting from unary_function/binary_function,
>   which is what the Standard itself started doing when these helpers
>   were deprecated.

Now you simply don't need it, so you can remove all traces of it from your program.

In C++14, transparent comparators were added. But it can be implemented in C++11. Just specialize it for `void`:

```
template<>
struct absoluteLess<void> {
    template< class T, class U>
    constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
      -> decltype(absolute(std::forward<T>(lhs)) < absolute(std::forward<U>(rhs)))
    {
        return absolute(std::forward<T>(lhs)) < absolute(std::forward<U>(rhs));
    }
}
};
```

Now the type can be deduced:

```
std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), absoluteLess<>());
```

Answer (score 22):

The only thing `std::binary_function` does is providing the member typedefs `result_type`, `first_argument_type`, and `second_argument_type`. And the only  thing in the standard library that uses these typedefs is `std::not2`, which is 1) strictly superseded by C++17 [`std::not_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn), 2) easily replaced by a lambda anyway, and 3) deprecated in C++17 and likely going to be removed in the next revision.

If, for whatever reason, you need to use `not2`, the legacy binders (`bind1st`/`bind2nd`, both deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17), or some ancient third-party thing following that protocol, the replacement is to define the typedefs directly in your class:

```
using result_type = bool;
using first_argument_type = T;
using second_argument_type = T;
```

Otherwise, simply remove the inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

`binary_function` can easily be replaced by `lambda` functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Lambdas can be declared in the global scope
auto absolute = [](auto& x)->float{ return x<0?-x:x;};

int main()
{
    // Lambdas can be declared embedded in functions
    auto absoluteLess = [&](auto&x, auto&y)->bool{ return absolute(x)>absolute(y);};
    auto absoluteGreater = [&](auto&x, auto&y)->bool{ return absolute(x)<absolute(y);};
    
    std::vector<float> input={-2.0, 0.0, 3.4, -123.0};
    std::cout <<  *std::max_element(input.begin(), input.end(), absoluteLess) <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<  *std::max_element(input.begin(), input.end(), absoluteGreater) <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Test it online](https://onlinegdb.com/Skxk-2tAQD)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: It would be nice if you showed how to implement it in the code from the question.

Comment: @Dharman: That seemed like overkill... std::function encapsulates anything that behaves like a function, with any number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar issue via [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (as suggested by ulatekh).
Applied to your code, it would look like this:

```
template <class T>
inline T absolute(const T &x) {
    return (x >= 0) ? x : -x;
}

template <class T>
struct absoluteLess : public std::function<bool(T, T)> {
    bool operator()(const T &x, const T &y) const {
        return absolute(x) < absolute(y);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct absoluteGreater : public std::function<bool(T, T)> {
    bool operator()(T &x, T &y) const {
        return absolute(x) > absolute(y);
    }
};
```

In other words:

Just replace

```
std::binary_function<X, Y, Z>
```

by

```
std::function<Z(X, Y)>
```

Where X, Y and Z are your types (Z is the result type).