# C++: How do I find out the return type of a function?

Tags: c++, lambda, return

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 5;
    vector<int> c{ 2,3,5,10,7,1,2,3 };

    auto foo = [a,b,&c](){c[a] += b;};
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, works, it executes the changes in the lambda function, but let's say I want to find out the exact return type of foo. Is it int, void, bool, etc.? Is there a way for me to cout it or something?

Comment: What have you tried? :P I am so sure you are not the first to ask such questions, did you search before posting?

Comment: I have asked similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863090/how-to-correctly-find-out-the-return-type-of-a-lambda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266391/find-out-the-type-of-auto